# DNN Page disappears

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have DNN 4.8 on a shared hosting server. I am facing a quite confusing situation. Whenever I add pages, after few minutes pages disappeared from menu and other page drop-down list (for example Parent Page Combo). Even this behavior repeated on DNN 5.1 as well. I am not sure whether this is issue with hosting company or DNN bug? any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not a standard DNN issue. My guess is it has something to do with the server caching and I would work with the hosting company to resolve it.

Does the page still exist? Is it just hidden in the menu? Does your login affect it?

Comment: Yup, it wasn't DNN issue. The system administrator allocated dedicate pool for my app in order to resolve this issue.